# pandas dataframe conditional selection

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

There is a pandas data frame.
One of columns named Exceptions.
Row represent entries. In Exceptions i store tuples.

i need to do a conditional selection of rows (there are other conditions which need to be &ed for further selection)

```
>>>print(dataframe.Exceptions)

0               
1               
2    (sfm, sfmp)
4               
3               
Name: Exceptions, dtype: object

>>>'sfm' not in dataframe.Expections
True
```

How to do this conditional selection with Tuples unpacked.

Appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Could you display a few rows of your dataframe and specify the condition?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example showing how to get tuples that have 1 in the second position.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'tups': [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1)]
})

filtered = df[df['tups'].apply(lambda tup: tup[1] == 1)]
print(filtered)
```

Output:

```
     tups
1  (0, 1)
3  (1, 1)
```

Is this what you're looking for?